# what is Jazz projects or Jazz based project?

Tags: eclipse, agile

What is the "Jazz Project" or Jazz based projects?

what is the role of Eclipse in Jazz based projects?

Its is a conceptual question.

I heard them in software engineering Podcast. but Don't Know much about them.  So detailed reply will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a suite of collaboration tools, which are based in a previous research sponsored by IBM.

You can browse the details (and some history) here:

**Original project:** http://domino.watson.ibm.com/cambridge/research.nsf/99751d8eb5a20c1f852568db004efc90/605fd62cb9a5a54485256e200066adf6!OpenDocument

**Products:** http://jazz.net/about/about-jazz-products.jsp

Answer (score 9):

(Note: I was a member of the team who built Jazz. I no longer work on the Jazz team but still work for IBM.)

Jazz is a family of technologies created by IBM's Rational division to enable software team tools and activities like software configuration management (SCM), bug and enhancement tracking, build automation, release and iteration planning, requirement management, test management, amongst other things.

Jazz was started in late 2004 by the Rational group because we realized that we needed a new technological foundation to help teams deal with modern challenges like geographically dispersed teams and governance and compliance issues.

There are several relationships to Eclipse. First of all, the original Jazz team was staffed with many of the same IBM folks who created Eclipse, e.g. John Wiegand, Erich Gamma, Jim des Rivieres, Nick Edgar, and Jean-Michel Lemieux, among others. Also, Eclipse technology played a bit role in the early days of Jazz. The first client technology we created was some new team extensions to the Eclipse IDE (this evolved into the Rational Team Concert Eclipse client). We also engineered the original server using Eclipse Equinox (the Eclipse implementation of OSGi) so that you could use the OSGi extensibility model to contribute server-side resources like web service endpoints, data model definitions, and web UI code.

Over time, we realized that extensibility via shared runtime wasn't going to work so we shifted over to a distributed extensibility model based on RESTful HTTP and RDF. We started an open community to define RESTful data models for team resources called "Open Services for Lifecycle Collaboration" (http://open-services.net/).

Finally, there has even been some influence of Jazz on Eclipse. When I started the Jazz Web UI code, at first I envisioned an extensible web UI much like the Eclipse UI (views, editors, etc.) but quickly pulled back on those ambitions when I realized how much work that would be to do the right way. However, over the years I collaborated with the IBM Eclipse folks talking about how we could achieve component reuse between browser and rich clients (Eclipse IDE, Visual Studio) and we also talked about how nice it would be if there could be a first-class browser story for Eclipse. After an extremely circuitous path, Eclipse.org with IBM's support proposed a new project called Orion (http://www.eclipse.org/orion/) which intends to provide this browser story for Eclipse.

So yes, quite a few relationships between Eclipse and Jazz. :-)

Comment: +1 for the most exhaustive answer, would gladly give you +2 if you'd add an TL;DR if it was allowed ;)

Answer (score 1):

I heard about this Jazz Process:

http://www.jazzprocess.com/concept/

there's also a book
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Jazz-Process-Collaboration-Innovation-Agility

it seems interesting

Answer (score 0):

> What is the "Jazz Project" or Jazz
>   based projects?

I *think* It's a framework for component-based server-side applications, focussing on collaborative software development tools. It's hard to make out through the veil of buzzwords.

> what is the role of Eclipse in Jazz based projects?

Presumably a lot of them are developed using Eclipse. You may also have heard them used together because Jazz is envisioned as a kind of "server-side Eclipse", i.e. a platform that aids development and integration of development tools.

Comment: I came across with this url. http://jazz.net/ it may be some how related to my question. I am exploring this.